# Prove a function that is nonnegative on a set then has a Riemann Sum that is greater than zero

Tags: real-analysis

Hey I have been working with Riemann Integrals and I have never sees this anywhere, but it makes intuitive sense to me and I can't seem to prove it.

If you have a continuous function that is real valued (say $f$) on an interval, $[a,b]$. Then $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$ then $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx >0 $.

Edit: I just realized this is only true if for some $x$ in the domain $f(x)>0$.

Comment: You mean $f(x) > 0$ for some $x$ in the domain. Use continuity to find a subinterval where $f(x)$ is strictly positive (say $f(x)>\delta > 0$), then use this to break up the integral into 3 pieces and bound it from below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f(x_0)>0$.  Let $\varepsilon=f(x_0)/2$.  By continuity, there is some $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in[a,b]\cap(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$, the value of $f(x)$ differs from that of $f(x_0)$ by less than $\varepsilon$.  And that implies $f(x)>f(x_0)/2>0$.  So $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ in some interval, and the integral of $f$ over the complement of that interval is $\ge 0$.